# LaTeX : build folder with name of project

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I work on TexMaker and when I compile a project, I chose to have a "build" folder for output files.
But as I have multiple LaTeX files, is it possible that each project has a specific "build" folder. For instance :

- project_1.tex creates the build_project_1 folder
- project_2.tex creates the build_project_2 folder
- ...
- project_n.tex creates the build_project_n folder

In this way, I won't need a subfolders in subfolders ... in subfolders !

Thank you !

Comment: by default latex always writes output to the current directory not a subfolder, and I'd always recommend keeping that default. Using `--output-directory` so tex redirects its output complicates the process for very little gain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.